# Is there a scope-managed file stream in C++?

Tags: c++, file, io

**Background**

Before the introduction of `unique_ptr` (or boost's scoped pointers) there was this kind of boiler plate pointer memory management everywhere.

```
int* a = new int(5);
// do stuff
delete a;
a = nullptr
```

Now we can just do

```
std::unique_ptr<int> a = std::make_unique<int>(5);
```

That's it! When `a` falls out of scope it will take care of all of the cleanup. Not only is it a convenience, it actually helps prevent memory leaks in the case of early returns or thrown exceptions.

**Question**

When writing to a file stream I notice the same boiler plate code

```
std::ofstream ofs;
ofs.open("out.txt");
// writing stuff
ofs.close();
```

Is there a similar mechanism to handle file opening and closing via RAII? So when the stream (or some kind of wrapper) falls out of scope, it will automatically fall out of scope and release the file handle? Otherwise we may have the same issue we had with pointers, where if you `return` early the file may not be closed.

Comment: file streams will close their file handlers when destructor is called, and you can pass the argument in constructor. Alternatively, you can always create a class that will store fstream and when destructor is called, call close on that stream

Comment: Really? So you do not have to explicitly `close` before returning from a function? All of those wasted lines of code I've written...

Comment: @Cyber Yup. The mechanisms behind streams are complicated, though [cppreference states](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream): "`(destructor)` *destructs the basic_fstream and the associated buffer, closes the file*"

Comment: Before `unique_ptr`, we used `auto_ptr` (or Boost's `scoped_ptr`, or a simple hand-rolled smart pointer, if we didn't like the crazy copy semantics of `auto_ptr`) to manage dynamic objects. Pointer-juggling has never been necessary within a single scope, only for transferring ownership between scopes (which `unique_ptr` fixes).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`ofstream` itself is scope-bound, with constructors that can open a file and a destructor that closes it. So you can just write

```
{
    std::ofstream ofs("out.txt");
    // writing stuff
}
```

with the same behaviour as your code, plus RAII goodness.

Comment: Looks like the standards committee is way ahead of me, as usual. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream the file will get closed when destructor is called, so file streams should be RAII already.

Comment: "If in doubt" - why would there be any doubt? `fstream` is specified to behave as you describe.

Comment: specified behaviour does not necessarily means implemented behaviour

Comment: @Creris then you cannot trust standard library at all and should rewrite everything. Who knows `ofstream::close()` may not close file handle.